# Julia worker generates broken pipe exception when using println

Tags: io, parallel-processing, julia

I've launched a number of Julia workers on a separate node using a custom ClusterManager. Standard TCP/IP transport.

I can run remotecall on the worker, but when I ask the remote worker to use `println` it fails with a broken pipe exception.

Any idea why this might be occur?

```
julia> remotecall_fetch(90, gethostname)
"gpu-8.local"

julia> remotecall_fetch(90, println, "test")
ERROR: On worker 90:
write: broken pipe (EPIPE)
 in yieldto at ./task.jl:71
 in wait at ./task.jl:371
 in stream_wait at ./stream.jl:60
 in uv_write at stream.jl:962
 in buffer_or_write at stream.jl:972
 in write at stream.jl:1011
 in print at strings/io.jl:46
 in print at strings/io.jl:18
 in println at strings/io.jl:25
 in println at strings/io.jl:28
 in anonymous at multi.jl:923
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:661
 [inlined code] from multi.jl:923
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:747
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:750
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question after a few more hours of sweat and tears. I had mis-understood a detail of the documentation. The cluster manager must maintain the stdout IO stream and pass it to the WorkerConfig.io field.

I noticed this line in the documentation:

- The cluster manager captures the stdout’s of each worker and makes it available to the master process

I had originally take that to mean only during the initial handshake when the workers write their IP/Port to stdout and that needs to be captured by the master to initiate the session. But now I see that the cluster manager needs to continuously redirect stdout from the workers to the master.